usb flash drive files are unable to be written to
when i make my usb writeable it works then deletes everything i wrote to it and doesn't empty it's trash ".Trash-1000" can't read files in trash and tried a bunch of commands from google and other things, so i'm stuck and need a pro's help
the usb drive's directory is "./media/chance/NEW NINTEND/"
the usb's name is "NEW NINTEND"
can't do anything
there is 2 adapters none are write-protected usb to sd and sd to microsd
i have root access

You've provided few specifics; we don't know what Ubuntu product/release you're using, and what file-system exists on your device, nor specifics of how you're accessing files (many methods won't use trash bins, others will, let alone file-system variations).

i'm on ubuntu (the OS)

Ubuntu Core, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop are all Ubuntu products, as are the various flavors of Ubuntu too, then there are release. We have no clues as to what Ubuntu product, or release of that product you're using. Your question is also specifically asking about a USB device where no file-system details are provided, thus we cannot know what is available unless we make assumptions; assumptions that could be misleading if incorrect.  Provide specific details.

ubuntu 24.04 the ubuntu desktop
the usb and sd cards are branded differently
the usb is nameless
the sd to microsd is a SanDisk converter
the MicroSD is a company called MicroSD

i tried chown and chmod none worked

The brands on the SD card matter less than how they're formatted; ie. what file-system are you using. You've provided no specifics as to mounting, or after writing data to if if you actually cleanly unmount after sync or ensuring data write completed.. This is a Q&A site and not a forum, comments are from readers to OP or Original Poster (or prior commentor) and answers will be to details in the question which still doesn't have details/specifics.  (comments will get removed once addressed in the question; cleaner questions (without comments) tend to get more attention & faster answers)

they're formetted in FAT32
